# Django Rest Framework, Relations POST option name

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

would like to know how to display the Album's name instead of "Album Object" in the POST Tracks' album 'option', refer to below image.

http://s27.postimg.org/8n2uakd9f/Screen_Shot_2014_12_29_at_6_29_07_PM.png

Here is my Model and serializer..

**models.py**

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Track(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, related_name='tracks')
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    duration = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('album', 'order')
        ordering = ('order',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%d: %s' % (self.order, self.title)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('order', 'title', 'duration','album')

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ('name', 'artist', 'year', 'origin', 'tracks')
```

**Album Data(Example):**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Album1", 
        "artist": "Artist1", 
        "year": "2012", 
        "origin": "Somewhere", 
        "tracks": []
    }, 
    {
        "name": "Album2", 
        "artist": "Artist2", 
        "year": "2014", 
        "origin": "Somewhere", 
        "tracks": []
    }
]
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can custom this label by defining the method `__str__` (or `__unicode__` in Python 2) in your model:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=50)


    def __str__(self):
         return "%s (by %s)" % (self.name, self.artist)
```

This function will be used whenever Django will have to print a reference to this object (including in django-rest-framework and the Django admin)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CustomRelatedField` to control how the object is displayed in Django REST Framework without having to change the Model's`__str__` or `__unicode__` method.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields